# Unable to parse some links from a local html file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the links connected to `View Bill` button within a table from a local html file. Here is the [file link](https://filebin.net/c8yngp1dwv9kjb0h).

This is how the first container looks like:

```
<tr class="clickable collapsed ng-isolate-scope blue-row" data-parent="#parent-table-body" data-target="#tr1" data-toggle="collapse" role="button">
<td>
<div class="accordion-icon" ng-enterclick="" tabindex="0"></div>
</td>
<td>09/18/2020</td>
<td>$183.47</td>
<td>10/02/2020</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>
<form action="/my-account/view-bill" class="hiddenForm ng-pristine ng-valid" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="actionType" type="hidden" value="View Bill" autocomplete="off">
<input name="billDate" type="hidden" value="2020-09-18" autocomplete="off">
<a class="link" data-action="View Bill  " data-category="billing_payment_history" data-label="Billing &amp; Payment History" href="https://www.duke-energy.com/?_ga=2.36159203.2592906.1601114887-735893428.1601114887" onclick="this.parentNode.submit(); return false;">View Bill  </a>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

local_file = r"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\htmlfile.html"

with open(local_file,"r") as f:
    page_content = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("#parent-table-body a.link:contains('View Bill')"):
    print(item)
    break
```

Output I'm getting from the first container:

```
<a class="link" data-action="View Bill  " data-category="billing_payment_history" data-label="Billing &amp; Payment History" href="" onclick="this.parentNode.submit(); return false;">View Bill  </a>
```

So, you can see that there is no link in the output above.

How can I parse the links from the view bill buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('htmlfile.html') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    target = [x['href'] for x in soup.select("a[data-action^=View]")]
    print(target)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and this is what I get `['https://www.duke-energy.com/home/billing/bill-inserts', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU be informed that my output based on the given `HTML` file which is count as _offline_ version from the website you are scraping.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. My first attempt is doing the same compared to the one you suggested. There is no website link in my post. What I did is give the link of some local html file produced by requests module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<tr class="clickable collapsed ng-isolate-scope blue-row" data-parent="#parent-table-body" data-target="#tr1" data-toggle="collapse" role="button">
<td>
<div class="accordion-icon" ng-enterclick="" tabindex="0"></div>
</td>
<td>09/18/2020</td>
<td>$183.47</td>
<td>10/02/2020</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>
<form action="/my-account/view-bill" class="hiddenForm ng-pristine ng-valid" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="actionType" type="hidden" value="View Bill" autocomplete="off">
<input name="billDate" type="hidden" value="2020-09-18" autocomplete="off">
<a class="link" data-action="View Bill  " data-category="billing_payment_history" data-label="Billing &amp; Payment History" href="https://www.duke-energy.com/?_ga=2.36159203.2592906.1601114887-735893428.1601114887" onclick="this.parentNode.submit(); return false;">View Bill  </a>
</form>
</td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for anchor in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'a' and re.search(r'View Bill\s+', t.text)):
    print(f"{anchor.text.strip()} - {anchor.get('href')}")
```

Output:

```
View Bill - https://www.duke-energy.com/?_ga=2.36159203.2592906.1601114887-735893428.1601114887
```

Comment: Hi @baduker, my one, your one and the one αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη has proposed are working flawlessly if I test them on the given container. However, they all fail if I try to do the same using the htmlfile that I've attached.

Comment: There's no value for `href` in the file you've attached as the urls are, I assume, generated by JS. `<a class="link" data-action="View Bill  " data-category="billing_payment_history" data-label="Billing &amp; Payment History" href="" onclick="this.parentNode.submit(); return false;">View Bill  </a>`